# How to create currentContext object in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, netflix-zuul

We have zuul 1 in which we have import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext; through which we are getting currentContext. as return getCurrentContext().getRequest();

How to create similar currentContext in spring cloud gateway?
we are using spring boot 3.2.0 version.

we tried to get through exchange.getRequest(); in spring cloud gateway. but it tightly coupled with filter() method. we need to decouple it similar in zuul 1.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.